# Unable to read a cpp parameter definition

Tags: c++-cli

In a .h file there is a function that takes in this parameter:

```
void (^callback)(float * arg)=NULL
```

as in a function definition:

```
void func(void (^callback)(float * arg)=NULL);
```

What I am able to read is that it takes a function pointer and if not defined it overrides with NULL. The part I do not get is the ^ in (^callback). I only know ^ as a bitwise XOR operator.
It also generates issues in my VS2012 compiler (something with CLR). So I would really like to rewrite this part to something else, without the bitwise operator...

Somebody has some ideas or able to explain this line of code?

Comment: This is code from Microsoft C++/CLI (which is a language with vague resemblance to C++). The `^` is not the bitwise-XOR operator, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is there something like that in C++/CLI? First I guessed it is something like delegates, but I can't find this syntax anywhere..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it is in C++/CLI. See the link in my comment

Comment: Aaah I see, so the "hat" declaration is used because of the option to completely ignore passing an argument. So the definition of 'callback' is deleted when NULL. So, to rewrite this I will use overloading and make two functions, one that expects a function pointer and one that does not. Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the `^` is a C++/Cli feature. So first you have to decide wether you want to do pure C++ or C++/Cli.

A C++ (non C++/Cli) version of your function could look like this

```
void func(void (*callback)(float * arg)= nullptr)
{
    if (callback)
    {
        float c = 1.0;
        (*callback)(&c);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I admit that I don't know what was intended with the original `^callback`. Because

```
void func(void (^callback)(float * arg)= nullptr)
{
    // ...
}
```

doesn't compile for me. Without the `float *` it still doesn't compile.